# BindingContext problem

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, combobox

I'm having problems with BindingContext in a .NET application. I need to populate 6 comboboxes with the same datasource but the first 3 comboboxes must be indepedent from the last 3 comboboxes.

I coded the following:

```
        combo_Bancos_cheque.DataSource = bancos;
        combo_Bancos_cheque.DisplayMember = "Nombre";
        combo_Bancos_cheque.ValueMember = "IDBanco";
        combo_ctas_cheque.DataSource = bancos;
        combo_ctas_cheque.DisplayMember = "NoCuenta";
        combo_clabe_cheque.DataSource = bancos;
        combo_clabe_cheque.DisplayMember = "CLABE";

        combo_Bancos_dep.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
        combo_Bancos_dep.DataSource = bancos;
        combo_Bancos_dep.DisplayMember = "Nombre";
        combo_Bancos_dep.ValueMember = "IDBanco";
        combo_ctas_dep.DataSource = bancos;
        combo_ctas_dep.DisplayMember = "NoCuenta";
        combo_clabe_dep.DataSource = bancos;
        combo_clabe_dep.DisplayMember = "CLABE";
```

The first 3 comboboxes work fine, when combo_Bancos_cheque changes combo_ctas_cheque and combo_clabe_cheque also change which is the expected behaviour. Then I create a new BindingContext to unbind 4,5 & 6 combobox which also use the same datasource. 
The problem here is: when combo_Bancos_cheque value changes, combo_ctas_dep & combo_clabe_dep also change but I don't want this, I need these comboboxes to change only when combo_Bancos_dep changes.

I'm new to BindingContexts, what am I missing?

Comment: What is the type of bancos - a DataTable?

Comment: is an object set, I'm using entity to SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quick guess, but don't you need to point combo boxes 5 and 6 to the same binding context as combo 4 (combo_Bancos_dep) ?

What if you create the new binding context into a variable, and then set it to CBs 4,5, and 6 ?

EDIT:
I just checked to confirm, and the above is correct.  You were really close, you just needed to set your new BindingContext to combo_ctas_dep and combo_clabe_dep.

Here is what you posted with the change:

```
    combo_Bancos_cheque.DataSource = bancos;
    combo_Bancos_cheque.DisplayMember = "Nombre";
    combo_Bancos_cheque.ValueMember = "IDBanco";
    combo_ctas_cheque.DataSource = bancos;
    combo_ctas_cheque.DisplayMember = "NoCuenta";
    combo_clabe_cheque.DataSource = bancos;
    combo_clabe_cheque.DisplayMember = "CLABE";

    BindingContext oBC = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingContext();
    combo_Bancos_dep.BindingContext = oBC;
    combo_Bancos_dep.DataSource = bancos;
    combo_Bancos_dep.DisplayMember = "Nombre";
    combo_Bancos_dep.ValueMember = "IDBanco";
    combo_ctas_dep.BindingContext = oBC;
    combo_ctas_dep.DataSource = bancos;
    combo_ctas_dep.DisplayMember = "NoCuenta";
    combo_clabe_dep.BindingContext = oBC;
    combo_clabe_dep.DataSource = bancos;
    combo_clabe_dep.DisplayMember = "CLABE";
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can infer, I believe the behavior is expected - you are binding the same source to the comboboxes.

I believe this statement:

```
    combo_Bancos_dep.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
```

does not do what you wish it to do - that is bind to a new source.

If "bancos" is a DataTable, you can remove the above line and just do a Copy on "bancos" to create a new DataTable and use that to bind your other combos:

```
DataTable copyOfbancos = bancos.Copy();
combo_Bancos_dep.DataSource = copyOfbancos;
combo_Bancos_dep.DisplayMember = "Nombre";
combo_Bancos_dep.ValueMember = "IDBanco";
```

Comment: I just made a quick sample to verify, and it is unnecessary to make a duplicate datatable to accomplish this.  By using a different BindingContext it can be done with minimal overhead, he just didn't get it put together quite right.